# instead of auto downloading dependent package, make NPM package use the version we downloaded directly

Tags: npm, package.json

I am working on a project in which I need to upgrade version of underscore NPM package from 1.7 to 1.8, but it is not a direct dependency of my project.

It is an internal dependency of some package, which i could not find.

So, i am thinking is there a way that i can make underscore NPM package a direct dependency of my project and make those packages which need them internally use the package which i have downloaded directly.

If it is not possible and if a better alternative exist then please let me know.

Comment: Unless it's pinned ("1.7.0" or "~1.7.x") somewhere then you should be able to install 1.8.0 and have it used everywhere - the default "^1.7.x" would allow it.

Comment: can you please elaborate. Do you mean i can just install underscore v1.8 directly and all the packages which require it internally will use the version directly installed by me ?

Comment: `npm list <package-name>`  will show which package it is used. Once you find the main package try installing the latest version of main package

Comment: Or `npm update <package>@<version>`, I think that does transitive dependencies too.

Comment: Check this also [How to install multiple versions of a npm package at the same time/project](https://dev.to/3imed_jaberi/how-to-install-multiple-versions-of-a-npm-package-at-the-same-time-project-2a29)

Comment: @kiranvj i used `npm list underscore` command and it listed down all the direct dependencies which are using `underscore` package internally. So my question is do i need to update all the packages which are using underscore v1.7 or just updating one of those will do the trick.

Comment: We can't tell you that, again it depends on the dependencies they have (`x.y.z` vs. `~x.y.z` vs. `^x.y.z`).